# create a JMeter https request with credentials (username and password)

Tags: https, jmeter

I want to create an https request to a server that requires username and password. Where can I provide the credentials? I couldn't find this option in the jmeter UI

Answer (score 4):

To set up jmeter to access an https url:

Create an HTTP Request Defaults with your server name.

Set implementation to httpClient3.1 (it didnt work for me otherwise)
Set protocol to https

Create an HTTP Request for the login

I used spring security, so I set path to /j_spring_security_check

Set method to post

In the parameters section, add the params you need to log in in the section called Send Parameters with the request. In my case I had to send a username and password param exactly as its defined in my login form.

Finally add a Response assertion to search for a text response. Here I checked for the full display name of the logged in person, since that shows up in the response.

If you want to save the cookie you might also want to create an HTTP Cookie Manager for the thread group

I followed this doc:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on authentication policy, if it's Basic Auth then it would be done through an [Http Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)
If it's form based, then passing them as parameters in Http Request will do it.

If you don't know your option is to record through browser and JMeter Proxy Server:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0):

### HTTP Request based Authentication

- Get your credentials names using **Developer tools** -> **Network** tab -> Your **POST Request** -> **Headers** tab -> **Form Data** section.

  [image: dev tools, network, headers]
- Create a **Test Plan** with some name and some elements
  [image: test plan elements addition]
- **HTTP Request Defaults**
  [image: http request defaults]
- Empty **HTTP Cookie Manager**
  [image: http cookie manager]
- Login **HTTP Request** with credentials specified
  [image]
- Required **HTTP Request**
  [image]
- **View Results Tree** listener
  [image]

Testing:
During Login Page passing jmeter gets a Cookie:
[image]

During a real request, jmeter uses the Cookie which have been set during Login Page passing:
[image]

Also, make sure you have `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` in your jmeter `user.properties` file. I've already done it earlier.

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/jmeter/bin/user.properties | grep Cookie
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

After file modification restart your jmeter.